# How to use Bubble Sort / qsort() in a struct to sort alphabetically

Tags: c, struct, quicksort, bubble-sort

I need to write a code where in a struct I register the license plate,model, brand, year and daily value of a car. After registering this data, I need to sort the entire struct based on the cars' license plate, and then display on the screen for the user. I am having the same trouble with the Bubble Sort as well as qsort(), it sorts only the first letter of the plate, so if i put "**ADB-1234**" for car 1, and "**ABC-1234**" for car 2, it won't swap and **ADB-1234** will be the first license plate, instead of second.

It should be like this, for example:

**INPUT**

```
Car 1

car plate: AGH-1234
car model: GTR
car brand: Nissan
car year: 2016
daily value of car: 100

Car 2

car plate: ABC-1234
car model: Corolla
car brand: Toyota
car year: 2014
daily value of car:50
```

Ordering...

**OUTPUT**

```
Car 2
car plate: ABC-1234
car model: Corolla
car brand: Toyota
car year: 2014
daily value of car:50

Car 1

car plate: AGH-1234
car model: GTR
car brand: Nissan
car year: 2016
daily value of car: 100
```

Here's the code with Bubble Sort:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

struct carro // STRUCT
{
    char placa[50];
    char marca[50];
    char modelo[50];
    char ano[50];
    char valordiaria[50];
};

struct carro car[3];


int x=0; //COUNTER



for(x=0; x<3; x++) // CAR REGISTER
{

    printf("\nCarro: %d", (x+1));

    printf("\nPlaca: ");
    gets(car[x].placa);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Marca: ");
    gets(car[x].marca);
    fflush(stdin);

    printf("Modelo: ");
    gets(car[x].modelo);
    fflush(stdin);

}

              //BUBBLESORT******

struct carro hold;
int o, pass;
int i=0;

for ( pass = 0; pass < 3 ; pass++ )//number of passes
    for ( o = 0; o < 3 - pass; o++ )//single pass
        if ( strcmp( car[o].placa, car[o+1].placa ) > 0)  
        {
            hold = car[o];
            car[o] = car[o+1];//swap array elements if statement is true
            car[o+1] = hold;
        }

printf("\n\nNomes em ordem alfabetica: \n");
for(x=0; x<3; x++) // MOSTRA NA TELA A STRUCT ORDENADA
{
    printf("\n\n\nCarro: %d", (x+1));
    printf("\nPlaca: %s", car[x].placa);
    printf("\nMarca: %s", car[x].marca);
    printf("\nModelo: %s", car[x].modelo);
    printf("\nAno: %s", car[x].ano);

}

}
```

Here's the code using qsort() :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct   // STRUCT
{
    char placa[50];
    char marca[50];
    char modelo[50];
    char ano[50];
    char valordiaria[50];
} carro;
carro car[3];

int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{

    carro *carroA = (carro *)a;
    carro *carroB = (carro *)b;



    return ( carroB->placa - carroA->placa );
}


int main()
{
    //struct carro car[3];

    int x=0; //COUNTER

    for(x=0; x<3; x++) // CAR REGISTER
    {

        printf("\nCarro: %d", (x+1));

        printf("\nPlaca: ");
        scanf("%s",car[x].placa);
        //fflush(stdin);

        printf("Marca: ");
        scanf("%s",car[x].marca);
        //fflush(stdin);

        //printf("Modelo: ");
        //scanf("%s",car[x].modelo);
        //fflush(stdin);
        /*
                printf("Ano: ");
                gets(car[x].ano);
                fflush(stdin);

                printf("Valor da diaria: ");
                fflush(stdin);
                gets(car[x].valordiaria);
                */
    }


    qsort (car, 3, sizeof(carro), compare);

    printf("\n\nSTRUCT ORDENADA: \n");
    for(x=0; x<3; x++) // MOSTRA NA TELA A STRUCT ORDENADA
    {
        printf("\n\n\nCarro: %d", (x+1));
        printf("\nPlaca: %s", car[x].placa);
        printf("\nMarca: %s", car[x].marca);
        //printf("\nModelo: %s", car[x].modelo);
        //printf("\nAno: %s", car[x].ano);
        //printf("\Valor da diaria: %s", car[x].valordiaria);
    }
}
```

Comment: `i < 3 - pass` ---> `o < 3 - pass` Btw don't use `gets()`.

Comment: Just use `qsort()`. Nice move to use struct assignment for the temporary in the swap, that made me very happy (most beginners don't get that).

Comment: `gets` and `fflush(stdin)` are both bad but vote to close for typo reason.

Comment: I tried to use qsort(), but it didn't compared the two first letters, only the first ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
return ( carroB->placa - carroA->placa );
```

The `placa` field is a pointer - C doesn't have real strings. And subtracting one pointer from another doesn't compare the strings, it subtracts the memory addresses of the two pointers.

You should instead compare the strings using the `strcmp` function. I'll leave it to you to read the docs on that one.

Comment: Oh man, thank you very much. I changed it to                              "return strcmp(carroA, carroB);" and it worked as i wanted!

Comment: It should probably be `strcmp(carroA->placa, carrobB->placa)`. The way you have works because that field happens to be the first one in the struct, but if someone adds a field and moves stuff around you could be in trouble later.